# 'const string' vs. 'static readonly string' in C#

Tags: c#

In C#, what's the difference between

```
static readonly string MyStr;
```

and

```
const string MyStr;
```

?

Answer (score 216):

When you use a `const` string, the compiler embeds the string's value *at compile-time*.
Therefore, if you use a `const` value in a different assembly, then update the original assembly and change the value, the other assembly won't see the change until you re-*compile* it.

A `static readonly` string is a normal field that gets looked up at runtime.  Therefore, if the field's value is changed in a different assembly, the changes will be seen as soon as the assembly is loaded, without recompiling.

This also means that a `static readonly` string can use non-constant members, such as `Environment.UserName` or `DateTime.Now.ToString()`.  A `const` string can only be initialized using other constants or literals.
Also, a `static readonly` string can be set in a static constructor; a `const` string can only be initialized inline.

Note that a `static string` can be modified; you should use `static readonly` instead.

Comment: +1, And the obvious conclusion, from a practical and semantic point-of-view: `const` should only be used for constants - constants being values that *never*, *ever*, *ever* change.

Comment: @LukeH _never, ever, ever_ is a little strong. I can't think of anything bad that would happen if one were to declare a private string as const and change it between two recompile events.

Comment: @Brenda: I'll admit that I do use `private const` for values that aren't, strictly speaking, constants; basically it's misusing `const` for micro-optimisation purposes. I'm going to stand by my *"never, ever, ever"* statement, even if it makes me a hypocrite. ;)

Comment: What about performance in case of strings in particular?
Will each const usage produce a new copy of a string in memory?

Comment: @Andrii no, constant strings are created once.  Each usage will have the same reference in memory.

Answer (score 55):

Here is [a good breakdown of the pros and cons](https://web.archive.org/web/20121110103312/http://devlicio.us/blogs/joe_niland/archive/2006/09/27/C_2300_-static-readonly-vs-constant-variables_3A00_-when-to-use-each.aspx).

Key points:

> At a high level, constants are obviously dealt with at compile-time,
> while static readonly fields are set at the time they are evaluated at
> run-time.

and

> The fact that constant values are subsituted by the compiler means
> that any library/assembly which references the constant value will
> need to be recompiled if the constant value changes. Libraries
> referencing a static readonly field will reference the field and not
> the value, thus they will pick up any change in the field without the
> need for recompilation.

and

> So, it appears that constants should be used when it is very unlikely that the value will ever change, or if no external apps/libs will be using the constant. Static readonly fields should be used when run-time calculation is required, or if external consumers are a factor.

Comment: Here is the Google cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&q=cache:804dblAZsCAJ:http://devlicio.us/blogs/joe_niland/archive/2006/09/27/C_2300_-static-readonly-vs-constant-variables_3A00_-when-to-use-each.aspx%2Bstatic-readonly-vs-constant-variables&gbv=2&&ct=clnk

Comment: The reference link is no longer available.

Comment: This is an excellent compliment to the answer marked as the solution. Defining the usage is very helpful. +1 from me.

Comment: Yes, for const the compiler will replace the variable with it's actual value wherever used, and for static it is looked up at runtime every time it is accessed.

Answer (score 21):

#### `const`

```
public const string MyStr;
```

is a **compile time** constant (you can use it as the default parameter for a method parameter for example), and it will *not* be obfuscated if you use such technology

#### `static readonly`

```
public static readonly string MyStr;
```

is **runtime** constant. It means that it is evaluated when the application is launched and not before. This is why it can't be used as the default parameter for a method (compilation error) for example. The value stored in it can be obfuscated.

Answer (score 8):

OQ asked about `static string` vs `const`. Both have different use cases (although both are treated as static).

Use const only for truly constant values (e.g. speed of light - but even this varies depending on medium). The reason for this strict guideline is that the const value is substituted into the uses of the const in assemblies that reference it, meaning you can have versioning issues should the const change in its place of definition (i.e. it shouldn't have been a constant after all). Note this even affects `private const` fields because you might have base and subclass in different assemblies and [private fields are inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950820/are-private-members-inherited-in-c).

Static fields are tied to the type they are declared within. They are used for representing values that need to be the same for all instances of a given type. These fields can be written to as many times as you like (unless specified readonly).

If you meant `static readonly` vs `const`, then I'd recommend `static readonly` for almost all cases because it is more future proof.

Comment: Who is this "OQ" you speak of?

Comment: “Original question”

Comment: Your comment about private const fields is inaccurate: private fields are inherited but they are not copied. The private field can only be referenced from the base class so will remain in the base assembly, the const field will not exist in the sub-class's assembly at all