# Enum-like class

Tags: c#, .net, string, constants, static-members

I am looking for a best practice on how to create enum-like class that instead of numbers contains string values.
Something like this:

```
public static class CustomerType
{
  public static string Type1 = "Customer Type 1";
  public static string Type2 = "Customer Type 2";
}
```

I would use this class throughout application as a value for all cases where I need CustomerType. I cannot use Enum because this is legacy system, and values like this are hardcoded everywhere, I am just trying to centralize them in one place.

Question is, in above example, should I use for declaring a variable:

1. static read-only keyword
2. const keyword
3. or just static

What would be a best practice to set these kinds of classes and values?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190870/const-string-vs-static-string-in-c-sharp.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should *not* use plain `static` because the fields could be inadvertently modified and cause mysterious breakage. Therefore, your two choices are `static readonly` and `const`.

`const` will cause the variable's value to be embedded in the calling code at compile-time, which would be effectively equivalent to the old hardcoded code (but with the advantage of a symbolic constant). The danger of `const` is that you must recompile everything if a `const` changes, lest you end up with out-of-sync constants and tricky bugs.

`static readonly` will result in a normal field access, so you won't have synchronization issues. However, you may take a slight performance hit due to the extra field access (though it is likely to be unnoticeable unless you use these fields a lot in performance-critical code). If you think you will have to change the strings at some point in the future, you will want to use `static readonly`.

From the sounds of it, the values will change rarely enough that `const` is a safe bet. However, the ultimate decision is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C#, Why not create an enum and set `string` based `Description` `attribute` for the `enum` values as below:

```
public enum CustomerType
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Customer Type 1")]
    Type1,

    [System.ComponentModelDescription("Customer Type 2")]
    Type2
}
```

Then, you can get the `Description` value of enum values as below:

```
int value = CustermType.Type1;
string type1Description = Enums.GetDescription((CustomerType)value);
```

For *various* other ways to get the `Description` attribute value of the enum, please refer this [SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650080/how-to-get-c-sharp-enum-description-from-value)

Comment: it is too "hacky", it is not straight forward, you need to do additional casting, code is not clear. You could do also like Enums.GetDescription((CustomerType)CustermType.Type1); but whats the point if I could have it straght forward with string CustermType.Type1String. Thanks anyway, I didn't know before about Description attribute :)