# Inheritance of C# private/protected members

Tags: c#, inheritance

Some say here that if members are protected you can access them:
[Are private members inherited in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950820/are-private-members-inherited-in-c)

Did someone really tried ?

I have tried it doesn't even work with protected:

```
public partial class Base
{
    protected IObject myObject;
}
```

If I derive (Base is in another namespace but it shouldn't matter I of course import that namespace)

```
public partial class Derive: Base
{

}
```

Intellisense doesn't show myObject in Derive Class.

So what I can do if I need a myObjhect member in all my derived classes to call some methods upon ? If I have to duplicate that member then what's the use of inheritance ?

Update: I forgot Derive:Base but that was just mystypo, of course I did that.

Comment: When you say: "Intellisense doesn't show myObject in Derive Class" you mean you're trying to access to `myObject` within a method of `Derive` class, not from the outside right ? Otherwise it's correct, you can't see it...

Comment: yes within a method of Derive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *actually* derive from the `Base` class:

```
public partial class Derive : Base
{
}
```

Comment: Then `myObject` should be accessible from the `Derive` class.

Comment: Finally It works but it's weird I had to recompile multiple times for that maybe it was due to assembly dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't deriving. To derive, you have to do the following:

```
public class Base
{
    protected IObject myObject;
}

public class Derive : Base
{

}
```

`myObject` is available in `Derive` now. Partial means you are splitting the class definition over multiple files.

Comment: It was mistypo, of course I derive from base but intellisense doesn't show myObject.

Comment: It should though... at least it does for me.

Answer (score 1):

> A derived class has access to the
>   public, protected, internal, and
>   protected internal members of a base
>   class. Even though a derived class
>   inherits the private members of a base
>   class, it cannot access those members.
>   However, all those private members are
>   still present in the derived class and
>   can do the same work they would do in
>   the base class itself. For example,
>   suppose that a protected base class
>   method accesses a private field. That
>   field has to be present in the derived
>   class in order for the inherited base
>   class method to work properly.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950820/are-private-members-inherited-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the base class when deriving? Should work with myObject declared as protected.

```
public partial class Derive : Base
{

}
```