# If we inherit a class do the private variables also get inherited?

Tags: c#, oop

If we inherit a class do the private variables also get inherited?

I know that "*Yes, the variables are inherited but cannot be accessed directly by the class interface.*"

**What I want to know is how can we access the private variables/methods from the child class**

*What I am trying to say is that private members are also inherited.But how to access the same without making them protected.*

Comment: You can't (well actually you can) because they're *private*.

Comment: Sorry guys if I was not able to make you all understand my query. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know is how can we access the private variables/methods from the child class
>   .........
>   But how to access the same without making them protected.

You might want to try using [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):
Here is a [similar question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/686623/1379664) that explains how this can be done.

Comment: Please don’t just post a link as the sole content of your answer.

Answer (score 10):

> I know that "Yes, the variables are inherited but cannot be accessed directly by the class interface."

So you know the answer then.

> What I want to know is how can we access the private variables/methods from the child class

You can’t, that’s why they are `private` (rather than, say, `protected`). The whole *intention* of making them `private` is so that you cannot access them from *anywhere*, notably including child classes.

Explicitly breaking this encapsulation is almost always a sign of a broken design and shouldn’t ever be part of a normal code flow. However, there are situations in which you want to reason *about* some code, and in these situations it may be necessary to examine even private values. Reflection libraries allow this. Here’s a simple example using the `System.Reflection` capabilities:

```
class Widget {
    private readonly string identifier;

    public Widget(string identifier) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }
}

class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var widget = new Widget("my_test_widget");

        var type = widget.GetType();
        var field = type.GetField("identifier",
                                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                                  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        Console.WriteLine($"{field} = {field.GetValue(widget)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: What I am trying to say is that private members are also inherited.But how to access the same without making them protected.

Comment: I answered that: you can’t access them directly.

Comment: But how to access them if you want to ? Ans is by using reflection !!

Comment: @NareshRavlani That’s a bad answer 99% of the time. The whole point of making something `private` is to *prevent* access. Don’t violate this, there’s almost never a reason.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Agree. But I was asked this question in an interview. So for me it was not about Why, it was about How.

Comment: @NareshRavlani That’s a good reason. I’ve included a minimal example in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Make them protected. For variables, make a protected property that the child classes then use.

Comment: +1 for protected properties. Protected contract is a contract too... It's a bad idea - to expose protected fields.

Comment: From the question "But how to access the same without making them protected."

Comment: @Matsemann The question was edited after I answered. That constraint wasn't there when I answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can only access private variables/methods from a derived class using [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135443/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-invoke-a-private-method-in-c). You cannot access them in a "natural" way, since the whole point of making them `private` is to hide them from other classes (including derived classes).

Answer (score 2):

Make it `protected` property instead of `private` member.

Comment: But no, please don’t, at least not variables. Use protected properties instead, otherwise you leak implementation details the same way as when making variables public.

Comment: The question is asked about how to access a variable or method only in child class.

Comment: Yes. But making variables `protected` is a *bad* solution.

Comment: From the question "But how to access the same without making them protected."