# GetMethod returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I have an asp.net web page. This is the class implementing the page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private readonly string delegateName = "DynamicHandler";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EventInfo evClick = btnTest.GetType().GetEvent("Click");

            Type tDelegate = evClick.EventHandlerType;

            MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("DynamicHandler", 
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

            Delegate d = Delegate.CreateDelegate(tDelegate, this, method);

            MethodInfo addHandler = evClick.GetAddMethod();
            Object[] addHandlerArgs = { d };
            addHandler.Invoke(btnTest, addHandlerArgs);


        }

        private void DynamicHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to hook up an event handler dynamicly. For some reason `method` remains null and I can't figure out why. I have done this many times before and I can't figure out what I'm missing.

**EDIT:** I found that `this.GetType()` returns the type of the page `ASP.default_aspx` and not the actual type implementing the page. I don't really know how to get around this...

Comment: Why aren't you just adding the handler directly? `btnTest.Click += DynamicHandler;`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Because I get the delegate method name as a string from our administration system.

Comment: In that case: Have you tested the sample code you showed here? Does it really reproduce your problem? Because to me, the code you showed looks good.

Comment: Working fine for me. `method` has a valid `MethodInfo`

Comment: Yes, it does reproduce the problem. Each and every time... Check my edit for why.

Comment: btnTest, is it ASP Server Button? Can you check the declaration type in partial page of code behind? Also check the page directive declaration section of aspx file, the class or type name with FQN or not.

Comment: `this` keyword gives the current instance reference only. If you have `DynamicHandler` in some other class you need to use `typeof(SomeOtherClass)`

Comment: Thank you all for your constructive comments :|

Comment: If you want always the declaring type, use `typeof(_Default).GetMethod(...)`. If you use `GetType().GetMethod(...)`, your problem is that `GetType()` finds the actual run-time type of the current instance, and that may well be a more specialized type than `typeof(_Default)`. Always use `typeof` keyword if what you want is a "constant" type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered in your edit, the actually ASPX page gets compiled into a class that *inherits* from `_Default` (where your code is located). So you need to make `DynamicHandler` (at least) `protected` rather than `private`.

<strike>Specify `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` also:</strike>

```
this.GetType().GetMethod("DynamicHandler", 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```

Comment: This will work. Also, I found out that `this.GetType().BaseType` would also work for the same reason. Thank you!

Comment: `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` is ***not*** relevant for non-static members. Inherited non-private non-static members are selected by default. (If you don't want them, use `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`.) The `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` is for inherited **`static`** members.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - thanks. I think I confused myself a lot with trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 7):

For the benefit of anyone else, `GetMethod()` can also return null if the arguments you passed do not match the arguments of the method you are trying to find. So, for example, if you are trying to find the method:

```
SomeMethod(int intParam, string stringParam)
```

You need to pass the parameter types to `GetMethod`:

```
type.GetMethod("SomeMethod", new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) });
```

Or, if you want to specify special binding flags:

```
type.GetMethod("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) }, null);
```

Comment: I've found this answer dozens of times and never seem to remember this...

Answer (score 4):

There are two things to be aware of.

**(1)** When you use:

```
this.GetType()
```

or equivalently just `GetType()`, the type which is returned is the actual run-time type of the actual instance. Since `_Default` is a non-sealed class, that type might very well be a more derived (more specialized type) than `_Default`, i.e. some class which has `_Default` as its direct or indirect base class.

If what you want is *always* the "constant" type `_Default`, use the `typeof` keyword, so use:

```
typeof(_Default)
```

instead of `GetType()`. This alone would solve your problem.

**(2)** Even if you specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic`, *inherited* `private` members are not returned. With your choice of binding flags, `private` methods declared in the same class (the derived class) are returned, but `private` methods inherited from base classes are not returned. However with `internal` and `protected` members, both the ones declared in the class itself and the ones declared in the base classes are returned.

This might make some sense, since a `private` method is not meant to be invoked from a derived class.

Changing the access level of your `DynamicHandler` method from `private` to e.g. `protected` (as suggested in the other answer) would be enough to solve your problem, as inherited protected members are selected when you use `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

It is still interesting that you can't get the inherited `private` members with `BindingFlags`. Related thread [C#: Accessing Inherited Private Instance Members Through Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686482/c-accessing-inherited-private-instance-members-through-reflection). It is possible to write a method that searches all base types, of course, like:

```
static MethodInfo GetPrivateMethod(Type type, string name)
{
    MethodInfo retVal;
    do
    {
        retVal = type.GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);
        if (retVal != (object)null)
            break;
        type = type.BaseType;
    } while (type != (object)null);
    return retVal;
}
```

That alone would also have solved your problem.